# Gauge invariance or diffeomorphism invariance in GR of observables?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, gauge-invariance, diffeomorphism-invariance

I am confused by the definitions of a gauge transformation, a coordinate transformation and a diffeomorphism. In particular, should observables in GR be fundamentally invariant under gauge transformations, coordinate transformations or diffeomorphisms?

For example, in [these notes by Bertschinger](http://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr5.pdf), observables should be gauge invariant, and he defines a gauge transformation as an infinitesimal diffeomorphism. This appears standard and in line with e.g. Sean Carroll's GR textbook.

On the other hand, there is [this paper by Yoo and Durrer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05839), which claims that cosmological observables are invariant under diffeomorphisms but not gauge transformations in general. Their definition of a gauge transformation appears to refer to simply "an equivalent" coordinate transformation - the sort which Carroll disagrees with being strictly correct in his textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetries are fundamental to the physical theory we want to describe. Mathematicians seemed to have understood that physical theories can be captured in a particular 'form' so to say. We do that in gauge theory on principal bundles, which is theory within differential geometry.

Skipping the details, the point regarding the gauges for GR is this: in general, GR can be written as a theory over a spacetime (just a Lorentzian manifold) $M$ with at each point $p \in M$ a specific coordinate frame $(\partial_{x^0}, \dots, \partial_{x^n})$ for some coordinate system $x^a$ on a subset $U \subset M$ (take a look of at the definition of a 'manifold'). The space of all frames is often denoted by $FM$. In this general framework, a *gauge transformation* is a smooth map $\Gamma$ transforming all the coordinate frames defined on each point of spacetime $M$ into other coordinate frames. Let us denote all us maps (called automorphisms) by $\text{Aut}(FM)$, and all gauge transformations by $\mathcal{G}$. So for GR, we have $\mathcal{G}=\text{Aut}(FM)$. This is the group of all transformations under which the physical theory stays the same, so it describes the exact same physical system.

You can imagine the following: a gauge transformation $\Gamma \in \mathcal{G}$ generally moves things in the underlying spacetime $M$, it therefore *induces* a transformation $\gamma:M \to M$. It can be proven that every such induced transformation $\gamma$ is a diffeomorphism, so $\gamma \in \text{Diff}(M)$. Actually, we can restrict ourselves even more: it turns out that there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{G} \cong \text{Diff}_0 (M)$ (read: a one-to-one identification). Here $\text{Diff}_0 (M)$ is the group of all diffeomorphisms on $M$ that are 'infinitesimal'. This is why Bertschinger is looking at solely infinitesimal diffeomorphisms, as it is exactly the gauge group $\mathcal{G}$.

This is interesting because of the fact that a general diffeomorphism can be constructed from a decomposition of multiple of these 'infinitesimal' diffeomorphisms. So that makes us also able to say that we want GR to be invariant under diffeomorphisms in general (at least those who preserve the manifold orientation).

Translating this to cosmological perturbation theory is actually very straightforward: we have a perturbation $\delta T$ on some tensor $T = T_0 + \delta T$, which we express in terms of coordinates $x^a$. If take gauge transformation $\Gamma \in \mathcal{G}$ then this is equivalent to taking a gauge transformation $\gamma \in \text{Diff}_0 (M)$. Locally, so that is in coordinates $x^a$ on the corresponding neighborhood $U \subset M$, we can express the effect of $\gamma$ in terms of how the coordinates $x^a$ change: $x^a \mapsto y^a$, and this is what this whole 'active' and 'passive' form of gauge transformations in cosmological perturbation theory is about. (Note: this transformation $x^a \mapsto y^a$ however does not transform in every coordinate system over the whole manifold $M$ in the same way as it is merely a local representation and $\gamma$ is a global transformation).

Note that under this (representation of) gauge transformation $x^a \mapsto y^a$, we have a transformation of the perturbation $\delta T(x) \mapsto \widetilde{\delta T} = \delta T(y)$, as the decomposition $T = T_0 + \delta T$ is depended on the underlying coordinates. Cosmologists then often mistakenly say that the transformations of the perturbations, like $\delta T \mapsto \widetilde{\delta T}$, are "gauge transformations". This becomes problematic, because this is not a well-defined notion of some spacetime symmetry such as $\mathcal{G} \cong \text{Diff}_0(M)$. That is the thing that goes wrong in the paper by Yoo & Durrer.

They however make a sincere point, but it is rather trivial: the only thing our physical theory, like GR or a cosmological model, can be invariant under is the gauge group $\mathcal{G}$, which are thus just diffeomorphisms of $M$, and not perturbation transformations $\delta T \mapsto \widetilde{\delta T}$. (There are more perturbation transformations than diffeomorphisms, so there is not a one-to-one relation.) The perturbation $\delta T$ is depend on the coordinate system but not unique. The error of the paper is calling a perturbation transformation, *in general*, a gauge transformation. This however happens frequently in cosmology.